# Convexity of $\frac{(x^TAx)^2}{\|x\|^2+1}$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, convex-analysis

Is the function $h(x)=\frac{(x^TAx)^2}{\|x\|^2+1}\quad,x\in\mathbb{R}^n\quad$ with $A$ symmetric positive definite convex?

I think yes, as the quadratic form in the numerator is easily seen to be convex. But the denominator is confusing me. Any hints? Thnaks beforehand.

Comment: Whether the quadratic form in the numerator is convex or not tells you very little. You can't in general divide a convex function by another convex function, and hope to get a convex function back.

Comment: @MishaLavrov so this example is not convex?

Comment: That also does not follow.

Comment: Interesting construction. Yeah, @MishaLavrov is right. In general, division is no bueno for preserving convexity. One fruitful method of showing a function involving division *is* convex is by using the theory of perspective functions (e.g. sec. 24.6 of Bauschke & Combettes' book, volume 2).

Comment: It might be worth fixing $x, v$ and considering the function $_{x,v}f(t)=h(x+tv)$. Then $h$ is convex if and only if $f_{x,v}$ is convex for every choice of $x,v$.  This is something you can then apply single variable calculus to.